# Contour plots that look like folded sheets in python

Tags: python, plot, graph

I found this diagram that represents magnetic field structures on a 2d plane. How can one produce a similar kind of graph in python? I have the required data.
Reference to the paper: [Amit Seta 2020 et. al.](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=njWm3FIAAAAJ&citation_for_view=njWm3FIAAAAJ:kNdYIx-mwKoC)

[image]